# Making use of available CPU time in a Network

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a very cpu intensive task which takes like 3 days on a core i7 6700k. I already work with threads, at the moment 16. I could easily split the task up to more tasks.

So I for the moment the option to go for java cuda to use up to 1000 threads.

But I have like 16 cores in the home network free to use.

So I wonder if its possible with java that I kinda join with each computer/build a node with it and that all cores in the node are running with the task.

Any idea if and how that is possible?

Thank you
Anna

Comment: Answer is **Yes**. But if you ask "how" we close you question as too broad.

Comment: How can I improve the question?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe if you take university course in networking and distributed computing it helps :)

Comment: the last keyword already helps me :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. First understand your problem.
2. Creating more number of threads wont solve your problem quickly, it will increase the problem only.
3. If it is IO bound operation (like reading disk content / writing data to some output devices) then CPU wont help in this case.
4. If it is analysis / encryption / decryption / calculations kind of stuffs then there you can split your task (Identify the task spliting logic so that each thread doesn't depend on others otherwise you will end up with problems).
5. Use thread pools for better utilization of threads. which will take care of thread creation / killing / resuse of existing threads /...)
6. If your task and data could be pushed into distributed frameworks like hadoop / spark then based on the task splitting logic work on that.

I think the above points would give better clarity and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Parallel Java 2 Library](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/pj2.shtml). It's both an API and a middleware to develop Java applications that executes on large computer clusters utilizing any CPU/GPU cores available. The API is well documented (Javadoc) and there is a textbook [BIG CPU, BIG DATA](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/bcbd/) available as well.